# R Plot_ly list Plots Multiple Plots in .Rmd R-Studio Run Mode, but not when Knitted

Tags: r, for-loop, rstudio, r-markdown, plotly

I am trying plot multiple plots from a list of data.frames.  I am using Markdown to render the data.  Within R-Studio, when I click the ">" run button, I get all the plots.

The code I am trying to use is:

````
### Plot each list
```{r plotSWBS6IByPhaseAndWave, echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE}
plotList <- list()

for(i in 1:length(seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave)) {
  plotList[[i]] <- plot_ly(data = seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave[[i]],
                 x = ~priceDate,
                 y = ~amount,
                 color = ~actionFigurePackageName,
                 colors = "Pastel2",
                 type = "scatter",
                 mode = "markers") %>%
                 layout(title = paste("Phase", seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave[[i]]$Phase, "& Wave", seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave[[i]]$Wave))
}
# p <- lapply(seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave, function(phaseWaveRow) plot_ly(data = phaseWaveRow, x = ~priceDate, y = ~amount, color = ~actionFigureUniqueId, colors = "Pastel2"))

print(class(seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave))
print(summary(seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave))

#rm(seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave)

plotList
```
````

The list looks like:

```
print(summary(seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave))
                                            Length Class      Mode
40th.1                                      35     data.frame list
40th.2                                      35     data.frame list
40th.Legacy                                 35     data.frame list
Blue.5                                      35     data.frame list
Blue.6                                      35     data.frame list
Blue.7                                      35     data.frame list
Blue.8                                      35     data.frame list
...
```

[image: Some data from the list]

The output in the run mode looks like:

[image: Run output]

The knit output just gives me the R Console output:

```
## [[1]]
## 
## [[2]]
## 
## [[3]]
## 
## [[4]]
## 
## [[5]]
```

If I try the following code, I lose the R Console output (which is good) and get the plots in R-Studio "run" mode, but get no plot output in the knit mode:

```
for(i in 1:length(seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave)) {
  print(plot_ly(data = seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave[[i]],
                 x = ~priceDate,
                 y = ~amount,
                 color = ~actionFigurePackageName,
                 colors = "Pastel2",
                 type = "scatter",
                 mode = "markers") %>%
                 layout(title = paste("Phase", seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave[[i]]$Phase, "& Wave", seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave[[i]]$Wave)))
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `htmltools::tagList` function:

````
---
title: "Knit a List of Plotly Graphs"
output: html_document
---

```{r, include = F}
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)
```


```{r, echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE}

dat <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
plots <- lapply(dat, function(x) {
  plot_ly(data = x, x = ~hp, y = ~mpg) %>% 
    add_trace(type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
})
tagList(plots)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Great! Some formatting and to match the original `m <- list(l = 50, r = 25, b = 75, t = 50, pad = 4)
xAxisList <- list(title = "Sale Date")
yAxisList <- list(title = "Value")
plots <- lapply(seriesFigureSaleDataBS6I_PhaseWave, function(plotData) {
  plot_ly(data = plotData, x = ~priceDate, y = ~amount,
          color = ~actionFigurePackageName,
          colors = "Pastel2") %>% 
    add_trace(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
    layout(title = paste("Phase", plotData$Phase, "& Wave", plotData$Wave), xaxis = xAxisList, yaxis = yAxisList, margin = m)
})
tagList(plots)`